# Upright subtitle in BibLaTeX

Tags: biblatex

I am using BibLaTeX with backend biber and philosopy-modern as style. What I am looking for: I want the subtitles of books, collections etc. in the bibliography to appear in upright font, i.e. not in italics as the maintitle.

Some months ago I found a solution (if I am right I redefined the title in the main document via `\renewbibmacro*{title ...}`), but inadvertently I now changed some characters and I can't remember how to reestablish my definition. What I had not done was to copy `\newbibmacro*{title ...}`, redefine it between `\makeatletter` and \makeatother simly by removing `[titlecase]` in front of `{subtitle}` (at least it doesn't work any longer).

Does anybody have any idea?
(I don't attach an example, because the problem remains the same with other biblatex-styles, different biber-options, redefinitions of various parts of the `biblatex.def` ...)

Comment: I wanted to say "upright shape" ...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip:  You can highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 5):

In the following example, I modified the `title` bibmacro as desired. Note that similar changes should be applied to the `booktitle`, `maintitle`, `journal`, `periodical`, and `issue` bibmacros (all located in `biblatex.def`).

Addendum: The modification is not obvious - it's only a closing brace removed from one code line and added to another. The effect is that `\printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}` isn't (anymore) part of the argument of `\printtext[title]`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{title}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{title}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{subtitle}}
  }
    {}
    {\printtext[title]{%
       \printfield[titlecase]{title}%
%       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}% DELETED
%       \printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}}% DELETED
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}}% NEW
     \printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}% NEW
     \newunit}%
  \printfield{titleaddon}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  subtitle = {An introduction},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. But the subtle change in the closing brace might not be obvious to future readers.  Can you explain briefly why this fixes the problem?  That way the basic principle will be more easily applied to other use cases.

Comment: Thank you! It works fine, for the most part: As an unexpected side-effect it puts only the "title" of articles in quotation marks, not the subtitle.<br/>   It works with subtitles in journals, if I refine your definition: Don't use title, but write only booktitle and maintitle!!!

Comment: @AlexanderWittmann The title/subtitle of `book` entries is controlled by the `title` bibmacro` -- `booktitle` is used, e.g., for `inbook`.

Comment: @lockstep @jon : After a short night: It does not work as fine as I hoped. By redefining the bibmacro title as suggested first, only the _title_ of articles in journals, collections ... gets enclosed by quotation marks (or however you mark these titles). By replacing all `title` by `booktitle` in @book-entries I prevent biblatex from printing anything at all (as @lockstep says).

Comment: @AlexanderWittmann Changing `title` to `booktitle` in the `.bib` file is surely wrong. Please update your question and specify exactly which subtitles in which entry types should be formatted upright.

Comment: @AlexanderWittmann -- Without more information about why subtitles need to be treated differently in different entries (either the subtitle is part of the title or it isn't), maybe you'd find the `titleaddon` field more appropriate for these entries.  As the manual says, the `titleaddon` (literal) field is 'an annex to the title, to be printed in a different font'.  E.g.: a book 'by'  J.C. Carrière and Umberto Eco: `title = {This Is Not the End of the Book},` and `subtitle = {Two Great Men Discuss Our Digital Future},` and `titleaddon = {A Conversation Curated By Jean-Philippe de Tonnac},`

Answer (score 0):

In the end I has to redefine the title and remove titlecase in the definition of subtitle.

That's what I did (and it works though it doesn't look very professional)

```
\renewbibmacro*{title}{%
   \ifboolexpr{
     test {\iffieldundef{title}}
     and
     test {\iffieldundef{subtitle}}
  }
  {}
{\printtext[title]{%
   \printfield[titlecase]{title}%
   \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
   \printfield{subtitle}}%
 \newunit}%
 \printfield{titleaddon}}

 \renewbibmacro*{booktitle}{%
   \ifboolexpr{
      test {\iffieldundef{booktitle}}
     and
     test {\iffieldundef{booksubtitle}}
   }
     {}
   {\printtext[booktitle]{%
   \printfield[titlecase]{booktitle}%
   \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
   \printfield{booksubtitle}}%
 \newunit}%
   \printfield{booktitleaddon}}

 \renewbibmacro*{maintitle}{%
   \ifboolexpr{
 test {\iffieldundef{maintitle}}
and
test {\iffieldundef{mainsubtitle}}
  }
{}
{\printtext[maintitle]{%
   \printfield[titlecase]{maintitle}%
   \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
   \printfield{mainsubtitle}}%
 \newunit}%
 \printfield{maintitleaddon}}

 \renewbibmacro*{journal}{%
  \iffieldundef{journaltitle}
{}
{\printtext[journaltitle]{%
   \printfield[titlecase]{journaltitle}%
   \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
   \printfield{journalsubtitle}}}}

 \DeclareFieldFormat[book, thesis, online, collection,
 proceedings, journal]{subtitle}{\textnormal{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[collection,
proceedings]{mainsubtitle}{\textnormal{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{booksubtitle}{\textnormal{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journalsubtitle}{\textnormal{#1}}
```